# How do I do these CodingBat problems?

Tags: java

How would I do these problems in CodingBat?

1.When given a char letter you will return the letter that is 10 places away.

```
tenLettersAway('A') → K
tenLettersAway('B') → L
tenLettersAway('C') → M
```

2.When given a String word change every letter to a letter that is 10 places away.

```
wordEncoder("HELLO") → "ROVVY"
wordEncoder("WORLD") → "GYBVN"
wordEncoder("MARY") → "WKBI"
```

3.When given an array of strings return the concatenation of all the strings separated by spaces.

```
sumOfArray({"cat", "ate", "dog"}) → "cat ate dog"
sumOfArray({"pig", "sleep", "softly"}) → "pig sleep softly"
sumOfArray({"Mary", "had", "a", "little", "lamb"}) → "Mary had a little lamb"
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you give any effort at all to do these on your own first? What's the point of "practicing" programming if we do all the work for you?

Comment: I did try. It just kept on giving me compiler errors!

Comment: `1)` Start by only asking about 1 question at a time. `2)` Post the code you wrote to solve it as an [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26954066/edit) to your question. `3)` Post the errors you received and what you don't understand about them.

Comment: Here's my code for sumOfArray.

Comment: public String sumOfArray(String [] arr){
  for (int i = 0; i<arr.length; i++)
  {
     String sums = arr[i] + " " + arr[i]; 
  }
  return sums;  
}

Comment: To tell you the truth, it doesn't even make sense to me.

Comment: As in, my code doesn't make sense.

Comment: Maybe start with a java tutorial or book then because these are some very basic tasks.

Comment: Ok. I will think about it a little more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know whether I should answer this question or not but here's how to do it -

`char` in java is just treated as a unsigned whole number. Therefore, to get a character 10 places away from it, you can just add 10 to the char. Here's a quick demonstarttion -

```
char vx = 'a';
vx = vx + 10;
// Now the value of **vx** is **k**
```

---

You can use a similar alogrithm to answer your second question like this -

```
String str = "HELLO";                 //Your string
char[] charArray = str.toCharArray(); //Convert it to a character array
```

Now the array must be like `['H','E','L','L','O']`

Now next step is to loop through the array, get a letter 10 characters away and then add it to a string.

Here is how to do it -

```
String encrypted = "";

for (char elements : charArray) {
    encrypted += (elements + 10);
}
```

The String encrypted should contain the desired encrypted string.

---

We can use the same trick to answer the third question.

Loop through the array, add the array elements and then separate them using spaces like this -

```
String myList[] = {"Cat", "ate", "dog"};
String fin = "";

for (String conc : myList) {
    fin = fin + conc + " ";
}

//finally remove the last extra space
fin = fin.substring(0, fin.length()-1);
```

---

#### Additional note :

The examples given above may not always works as expected. There might be some cases like this -

```
char a = 'z';
a = a + 1;
```

The example given above will not print **a** but it will print **{** because it is the next character to **z** in the Unicode table.

Refer to the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) (or [Unicode table](http://unicode-table.com/en/#control-character) for a more broader view) to identify such cases and eliminate them.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for the inspiration! I had no clue how to do it before.